# How to set DataContext in a Dialog Window to its parent's DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I created a new Window which I then call using the following code:

```
NieuwSimulatie NiewSimulatieWindow = new NieuwSimulatie()
{
    Owner = this
};

bool? SimulatieAangemaakt = NiewSimulatieWindow.ShowDialog();
```

In the Window "NieuwSimulatie" I'd like to have the same DataContext as in my MainWindow, or I would like to DataBind the controls directly to the DataContext using RelativeSource I geuss, Ive tried:

```
<Controls:SplitButton x:Name="ProjectNaam"
                      DisplayMemberPath="ProjectNaam"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Static.Projecten, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Controls:MetroWindow}}"/>
```

But this doesn't work.

Please help me either fix my DataBinding or help me set the DataContext of my Window to the DataContext that is behind MainWindow.

Comment: Do you mean `DataContext = this.DataContext` when you create child window?

Comment: I tried this and it returned null, now I realise this is because the window wasn't finished constructing yet. Im an idiot :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've you have acces to your DataContext from where you create your window, how about that:

```
NieuwSimulatie NiewSimulatieWindow = new NieuwSimulatie()
{
    Owner = this,
    DataContext = YourDataContext;
};

bool? SimulatieAangemaakt = NiewSimulatieWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you ask is typically done when creating the new window, because they are two Windows it's better to pass the context in...like this:

```
NieuwSimulatie MyNewWindow = new NieuwSimulatie(DataContent);
MyNewWindow.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do it like this :

```
NieuwSimulatie NiewSimulatieWindow = new NieuwSimulatie()

NiewSimulatieWindow.DataContext=this.DataContext;

bool? SimulatieAangemaakt = NiewSimulatieWindow.ShowDialog();
```